# Requires best practices/Approach for searching user from active directory group which is added in SharePoint group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Requires best practices for searching user from active directory group which is added in sharepoint group

I have a scenario where i need to search a user from active directory group which is added in 
sharepoint group. What is the best way to search a user in this scenario 
Example. I have one group called "Employee" and i have added one active directory security group called "IndiaEmployee". into the Employee group 
I have a webpart where i added one textbox and gridview. whenever i search for a user it should it search in active directory as i mentioned in above. 
What is the best way to acheive this with better performance.

Regards,

Navaneetha Krishnan D

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure whether this will help you or not but this is a way for your solution.

http://adbrowser.codeplex.com/

http://sp2010adgroupmembers.codeplex.com/

http://sharepointrookie.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/display-site-members-from-ad-groups/

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)